# Use user control in xaml

Tags: wpf

I think I'm missing something very obvious.
I create a WPF application and a user control. Both within one project in Visual Studio. In the WPF application I want to use the user control but the compiler pretends not to know the user control:

*Error  1   UserControl1 is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project*

Here is the WPF application XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <UserControl1></UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

And this is the XAML code of my control

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Label>Hello World</Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have missed declaration of the [namespace in your xaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: @JohannesSchacht because you can name two different Elements by the name name. What will make the difference between those two is their namespace. Think of the namespace like a folder path.